# Is there any way to extract Boost Regex so I can package it with my project?

Tags: c++, regex, boost, g++, boost-regex

I'm working on a project written in C++ that uses the Boost Regex library to do some parsing.  My problem is, I need to run the program on a remote machine that doesn't have the boost library installed.  I also don't have admin access to this computer so I can't just install it myself.

Is there any way to separate out just the Boost Regex library so that I can put it in the same directory as my other code?  I tried doing this already by downloading the boost library and separating out all of the unneeded headers and such.  I managed to get it to a point where it calmost compiled but it failed at the linking stage.

Is there anything I can do to fix this or will I be forced to rewrite the parsing code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Boost.BCP](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html) tool to extract a subset of Boost.

Answer (score 2):

include the static library  `libboost_regex-gcc-1_35.a`  your list of object files to compile.
1_35 is an older version number on my linux box, you may have a newer library

Comment: Thanks this helps,but how do I now deal with the problem of header files?  boost/regex.hpp seems to include cause a lot of other things to be included.